# Do I have to buy dynos too for my staging application on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, devops, production-environment, staging

I'm using **Heroku** as a platform for my **Django** application, **currently on a free dyno**. I have created a copy of my application in order to seperate staging and production applications. Now before the application launch, I'm willing to upgrade to Standart2X dyno tier on Heroku for my production app, to use multiple process for background tasks.

The things is my app really depends on background tasks (slow and high number of API calls), so I want be able to **test** **multiple process's working in staging enviroment before pushing to production**.

What I don't understand is, do I have to upgrade my dynos both in staging and production enviroment? Maybe I can use hobby tier dynos in staging (which allows defining multiple process types in Procfile too) as they are cheaper than standart dynos, but this feels wrong as application sources will be different for staging and production. Maybe I'm missing something here or I don't understand these concepts enoughly.

I'm kinda new to staging-production concept, so I appreaciate all kind of helpfull links and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world the staging server would be exactly the same as production, even with the same data, so every new release can be validated on an environment which does not differ from what the real users access.

Having said than it does (almost) never happen, simply because it requires higher cost (staging server with the same specs as prod) and maintenance (data copy, etcc.)
Some systems and applications require the highest quality and safety (ie critical systems in healthcare, security, etc.) so they do invest in such architecture.

In your case I would suggest a smaller staging environment (Free or Hobby) which is good enough to validate the new features before releasing.

Comment: Of course, this has an impact on your initiation process, which is divided into 3 general steps:
1. Development and push into VCS
2. Deployment from VCS into Heroku-staging and testing (Dyno type: free or Hobby)
3. Deployment from VCS into Heroku-live after bug fix (Dyno type: fully paid)